# Simple trees for mathematics

Tags: forest, trees, qtree

I have to draw many simple trees similar to the ones depicted for instance at page 128 or 133 of [this beautiful book](http://cheng.staff.shef.ac.uk/guidebook/guidebook-new.pdf) by Cheng and Lauda. I used to have some knowledge of the package *forest*, but unfortunately I now realise that I have forgotten most of it (although I guess I should play with the *circle* or *encircle* option, somehow).

The best would be a simple macro using *forest* or *qtree* allowing to draw these upward growing, unlabelled trees.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could start here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={%
    label/.option=content,
    grow=north,
    content=,
    circle,
    fill,
    minimum size=3pt,
    inner sep=0pt,
  }
  [
    [ [][] ]
    [ [][][][] ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wonderful, many thanks! Quick remark for anybody interested in the same question: with the option *grow=north* the tree is drawn from right to left; in case you prefer the left to right version, then right option is *grow'=north*.

Answer (score 4):

I've no experience with `forest` (DG's answer seems a good place to start) but have recreated one of the figures in the book using the tikz `trees` library (only), in case you decided that the forest package wasn't necessary and/or were already familiar with drawing in tikz.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[
level 1/.style={grow via three points={one child at (0,1) and two children at (-.5,1) and (.5,1)}},
level 2/.style={grow via three points={one child at (0,1) and two children at (-.25,1) and (.25,1)}},
level 3/.style={grow via three points={one child at (0,1) and two children at (-.125,1) and (.125,1)}},
every node/.style={circle, fill=black, inner sep = .25ex, minimum size=.25ex}]
\node {} 
child{
    node {} 
    child{
        node {}
        child{node {}}
        child[very thick]{node {}}
        child{node {}}
        }
    child{
        node {}
        }
    }
child{
    node {} 
    child{
        node {}
        child foreach \x in {1,2,3} {node {}}
        }
    child{
        node {}
        }
    }
child{
    node {} 
    child{
        node {}
        child[red]{node {}}
        child[missing]
        }
    child{
        node {}
        }
    }
child{
    node {} 
    child{
        node {}
        }
    child{
        node {}
        child{node {}}
        child[missing]
        child{node {}}
        }
    child{
        node {}
        }
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: tree_example]

The drawing trees with tikz is explained in section 21 Making Trees Grow of the tikz manual. Noteworthy in this example:

- The coordinates in each `style` at the start of the picture determine the placement of children at the level indicated
- Individual children (edges) and nodes (vertices) can have their own styling (for example, `very thick`)
- The `missing` key is useful to create a child that 'takes up space' but is not visible (such as that adjacent to the edge highlighted in red above)
- If all children are going to be the same, you can use a `foreach` construct